# Javascript function is not being called immediately from server side

Tags: asp.net

On a button click event, I'm calling a JS function, but its being called after all lines of click event finsihes off. Why and how to resolve this?

*I want the JS function -  "ConfirmAcceptance" should be called first and display the confirmbox alert, before executing the server side function - "DoSomething".*

**EDIT:** Please Note, that I have certain validations which must be performed on server side click event(like fetching database values) and based on this result only I can call the required JS confirm-box.

**Server:**

```
protected void ApplyButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

            //Database values are fetched and these values are validated.
            if (validations are true)
            {
                Flag.Value = "true"; 
                break;
            }            

        if (Flag.Value == "false")
            ApplyRestrictionFlag();
        else
        {
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "Javascript", "javascript: ConfirmAcceptance(); ", true);
            if(Accept.Value == "true")
                DoSomething();
        }

    }
```

**Client:**

```
function ConfirmAcceptance()
{
    var accepted = confirm("Click OK to accept terms");
    if(accepted == true)
        Accept.Value = 'true';
}


<asp:Button ID="ApplyButton" runat="server" OnClick="ApplyButton_Click" Text="Apply"/>

<asp:HiddenField ID="Flag" runat="server" Value="false" />
    <asp:HiddenField ID="Accept" runat="server" Value="false" />
```

Comment: why not to use `OnClientClick` property ?

Comment: i have certain validations which must be performed on server side click event and then based on the result load the required alert.

Comment: @codefly: "Accept" is a hidden field.

Comment: You are misunderstanding an important part of the client/server architecture in ASP.NET. `RegisterClientStartupScript` was named that for a reason. It means that when the postback has completed and the page has reloaded on the client side, that JavaScript will execute. It does not mean "execute this immediately", the web would have to work differently and they would have renamed it `ExecuteClientSideScript` instead.

Comment: @mason - you sound logical here. thanks. But what shall I use instead ?

Comment: Start by understanding that the server side can _never_ "call" the client side, and I'm sure you'll figure it out.

Comment: You have a couple options. You can use AJAX to call the server and perform the validation. Or you can just check the hidden field from JavaScript. I'd personally shy away from using any JavaScript `confirm()` or `alert()` as you don't have control over them. Instead, create your own popup dialogs using tools such as [ModalPopupExtender](http://www.asp.net/AjaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/ModalPopup/ModalPopup.aspx) or [Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/).

Comment: I have used Ajax before. But actually I was thinking if there's a less complicated way just to "get a OK or CANCEL click event in a pop-up". but still thanks for all suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Handle the [OnClientClick](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.onclientclick%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event

```
function ConfirmAcceptance() {
    return confirm("Click OK to accept terms");
}

<asp:Button OnClientClick="return ConfirmAcceptance();" OnClick="ApplyButton_Click" />
```

This will make sure your client validation is run first *then* the server validation.

Comment: Thanks James, but it won't help my particular case. I have certain validations which must be performed on server side click event and based on this result only I can call the required JS confirmbox.

Comment: @Kings maybe want to reword your question then because at the minute it says "*I want the JS function - "ConfirmAcceptance" should be called **first** and display the confirmbox alert, **before** executing the server side function - "DoSomething"*"

Comment: Correct, I added more details to my question.

Comment: @Kings so really, you don't want client-side validation *at all*. You want server-side validation and you want to display the response on the client. I would recommend using AJAX for that instead.

Comment: AJAX, yeah I know. I have used it before, just need to have some brush up on that. Actually I was thinking if there's a less complicated way just to "get a OK or CANCEL click event in a pop-up".